# Performance Testing with SOAP Messages

Tags: web-services, node.js, soap, performance-testing

I have to complete performance testing using SOAP messages.
Instead of targeting the real SOAP URL end point i need to hit a "Mock" URL end point and return "pre recorded" SOAP responses that could be held in a local database or cached in memory.

This "Mock" SOAP response server needs to be able to perform up to 1000 transactions per second. It also needs to be configurable, e.g. set a delay in responding with the matched SOAP response etc..

I have been looking at building a Node.js clustered HTTP server with the SOAP Response messages stored in a local mongoDB.

I will have a multi core machine to run this Mock server on, e.g. 96 cores.

I need to be able to interrogate the incoming SOAP requests to match them to the correct SOAP responses.

Can anyone suggest a node js module that allows me to extract data from SOAP responses.

Or suggest a "better" way to approach the entire project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bit belated response for you but next time you have a similar challenge you might wanna try the [SOAP/REST Mock Service](https://sourceforge.net/p/soaprest-mocker). It's a lightweight web app allowing to configure series of responses and response delays as well as to verify requests.